# Prove that the following limit exits and compute its value: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}\right)e^{-2x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Prove that the following limit exits and compute its value:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}\right)e^{-2x}dx$$

---

Attempt. If such a limit exists then we have $$\int_0^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}\right)e^{-2x}dx=\int_0^\infty \cos(x)e^{-2x}=2/5$$

We now want to prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=2/5$$ where $a_n=\int_0^n\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}e^{-2x}dx$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$

Let $\epsilon > 0$. We need to find $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $|a_n-2/5|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$. But, the computation seems heavy. I would be glad if someone could help me. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Comment: Hint: if $0 \leq x \leq n$, $\left|\cos{x}-\sum_{k=0}^n{(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}}\right| \leq \frac{x^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!} \leq \frac{n^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!}$ which is very small…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$| \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac {(-1)^{k} x^{2k}} {(2k)!}| \leq \sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac { x^{j}} {j!}=e^{x}$ and $e^{x}e^{-2x}$ is integrable. So we can apply DCT.